# Should "nlhe" and "texas holdem" be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently these are our most used tags. That is something I would expect to remain constant. Any question that is tagged "nlhe" could also be tagged "texas holdem" however there is the potential for "texas holdem" to be used on pot-limit and limit questions as well as nlhe questions. In that line of thinking, it makes sense for it to stand on it's own.

The only reason I question this, however, is that by having the nlhe tag separate, we are already seeing some questions with only "nlhe" and others with only "texas holdem". That leads to making it hard to find all questions on the topic.

Thoughts?

Comment: I guess this echoes back to this question: http://meta.poker.stackexchange.com/questions/36/do-we-need-to-allow-6-tags Perhaps we need to rethink things...

Answer (score 3):

You're not alone as I've thought about this too.

The way I see it, one is generic ([texas-hold-em](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texas-hold-em)), and one is specific ([nlhe](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlhe)). For broader but acceptable questions that cover theory pertaining to a mix of limit, pot-limit, and no-limit varieties it would make sense to have one tag to cover them all. Obviously, if a question is relative to only one variant then, lhe, plhe, and nlhe all become reasonable tags to include.

Clearly, it's not perfect but I think having the two tags is better and guiding questioners to be specific with the tag variant where it's applicable is *currently* the preferable course of action.

Just what I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think they should stay separate.  There are certainly posts that belong only in one tag or the other - a question on pot odds should be tagged `texas-hold-em`, and one that includes large betting considerations on future streets would certainly need to be tagged with `nlhe` (or `plhe`, if that was the case) - the theory wouldn't apply to fixed limit.  In fact, I think there are few questions that should be tagged with both `nlhe` and `texas-hold-em`.